# Swift multiline strings are not formatted correctly

Tags: bug, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting

Swift multiline strings that contain quotation marks, such as:

```swift
    let multilineString = 
    """
         "let myString = 123"
        is part of my multiline string
    """
```

are formatted incorrectly. For example see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53022560/386738)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) as there is a paragraph about bugs and how and where to report then. The tl;dr of that is that bugs in the highlighting  should be directed at the Google Code Prettify GitHub repositiory.